# Перебрать два массива JavaScript

Tags: javascript

В одном массиве я получаю данные из textarea, перебираю его регулярками из другого массива. Я застрял, немного не понимаю Javascript.
Мне нужно записать найденные ссылки в один блок, другие ссылки (которые не прошли по регуляркам) в другой блок. На регулярки не обращайте внимания, просто хотя бы если в ссылки присутствует слово из массива - записать в блок.

```
let myText = ['https://www.fdsfsdfsdfsdfd.ru/hack', 'https://www.fdsfsdfsdfsdfd.ru/fdsgdvzlom'];
let reg = 'hack';
let array = [];

function filter(myText, reg) {
for(site of myText) {

let access = site.includes(reg);
console.log(site);

if(!access) {
array.push(site);
}
}
}

filter(myText, reg);
console.log(array);
```

Получилось только со строкой (reg), но я хочу reg сделать массивом и добавить больше регулярок туда. Я новичок в Javascript, поэтому любая помощь подойдет!

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
const input = ['cat', 'can', 'dog'];
const patterns = ['ca', 're', 'ab'];

const validInput = [];
const invalidInput = [];

// для всех строк
for (let str of input) {
   let isValid = true;

   // проверяем, что строка соответсвует всем правилам
   for (let pattern of patterns) {
      // здесь может быть регулярка
      if (!str.startsWith(pattern)) { 
          isValid = false;
      }
   }

   if (isValid) {
       validInput.push(str);
   } else {
       invalidInput.push(str);
   }
}
```